# qemu not a valid device model name

Tags: virtualization, qemu, device-driver

I followed  https://github.com/levex/kernel-qemu-pci to build a custom device. After building it along with the qemu source code (using "make" command), I ran

"qemu-system-x86_64 -m 256 -kernel arch/x86_64/boot/bzImage -initrd initrd.img -hda disk1.img -append root=/dev/sda -curses -s -device pic_levdev"

on my Linux vitual machine. But I get the error  "pci_levdev: not a valid device model name".

I followed the below link to install qemu:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S1WsIbxbd_k

Any idea what I might be missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you're running the QEMU you just built (the executable will be in the x86_64-softmmu/ subdirectory), and not an old qemu-system-x86_64 on your PATH ?  I suggest you specify the path to the new binary explicitly when running it.